# How do I bind my properties from my ExpandedHomeSlider class to SPListItemCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, sharepoint-2010, user-controls

I created the Public Classes HeroImage and ExpandedHomeSlider to access a custom list that will be given to the Repeater in order to allow the modifications of the SPListItem easily. **How do I bind my properties from my ExpandedHomeSlider class to SPListItemCollection?** I am new to SP development. Any help is appreciated :].

```
public partial class HomePageHeroRotator : UserControl
{
    public SPListItem SpListItem;

    public class HeroImage
    {
        public SPListItem SpListItem;
        public string heroImageUrl
        {
            get { return SpListItem["HeroImage"].ToString(); }
        }
        public string heroImageUrl2
        {
            get { return SpListItem["HeroImageCallOut"].ToString(); }
        }
    }
    public class ExpandedHomeSlider 
    {
        public SPListItem SpListItem;
        public string explanatoryText
        {
            get { return SpListItem["ExplanatoryText"].ToString(); }
        }
        public string attentionExplanatoryText2
        {
            get { return SpListItem["ExplanatoryText"].ToString(); }
        }
        public string explanatoryText2
        {
            get { return SpListItem["ExplanatoryText"].ToString(); }
        }
        public string homeSliderImageUrl
        {
            get { return SpListItem["ExpandedSliderImage"].ToString(); }
        }
        public string GreenFlyoutText
        {
            get { return SpListItem["GreenFlyoutText"].ToString(); }
        } 
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Query List for all List Items
        //ASCX to render list items
        SPSite site = null;
        if (SPContext.Current != null)
        {
            site = SPContext.Current.Site;
        }
        SPList list = site.RootWeb.Lists["HomePageHero"];

        SPListItemCollection myItems = list.Items;
        IEnumerable eList = myItems.Fields as IEnumerable;

        //foreach loop 

        HomePageHeroRpt.DataSource = eList;
        HomePageHeroRpt.DataBind();
```

}

My Schema.xml List has these fields:

```
        <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" />
      <FieldRef Name="ExplanatoryText" />
      <FieldRef Name="GreenFlyoutText" />
      <FieldRef Name="BrownFlyoutText" />
      <FieldRef Name="RedFlyoutText" />
      <FieldRef Name="OrangeFlyoutText" />
      <FieldRef Name="LightBlueFlyoutText" />
      <FieldRef Name="BlueFlyoutText" />
      <FieldRef Name="AttentionExplanatoryText" />
      <FieldRef Name="ExplanatoryText2" />
      <FieldRef Name="HeroImage" />
      <FieldRef Name="HeroImageCallOut" />
      <FieldRef Name="ExpandedSliderImage" />
    </ViewFields>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first think you need to do is transform your collection of `SPListItem` objects into a collection of your custom objects.  `Select` is a LINQ method that can do this for you.  Then you can just bind that to your repeater:

```
HomePageHeroRpt.DataSource = list.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
    .Select(item => new ExpandedHomeSlider(){SpListItem = item});
```

On a site note there is a tool called "SPMetal" that is capable of generating classes like this for you, so that you don't need to create them on your own.  (They have their fair bit of design differences, but the general goal of having a property for each field is the same.)

Comment: //Hmm I thought I am supposed to use a foreach loop similar to this?
            foreach (ExpandedHomeSlider field in myItems)
            {
                myItems["ExplanatoryText"] = field.ExplanatoryText;

            }

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, but isn't there a way to do it with a foreach loop not a linq statement? @Servy

Comment: @Fawn There are certainly solutions one could write that would use a `foreach` loop.  What you provided won't do what you want, but if you *really* wanted to explicitly write a `foreach` loop you could write a solution that would do so.  I see no compelling reason to do so here.  It certainly wouldn't improve the code any.

Comment: I am confused on if I did a foreach loop what would go inside my loop?             foreach (ExpandedHomeSlider item in myItems)
            {
                myItems.??? = item["ExplanatoryText"].ToString();
            } @Servy

Comment: @Fawn The easiest option would probably to ccreate a `List<ExpandedHomeSlider>` and then for each `SPListItem` you convert the object and add it to the list, then bind to the list.

Comment: //foreach loop 
            foreach (SPListItem item in myItems)
            {
                List<ExpandedHomeSlider> expandedSliderList = new List<ExpandedHomeSlider>();
                for (int i = 0; i < expandedSliderList.Count; i++)
                {
                    expandedSliderList.Add(item);
                }
            } @Servy I don't know if this is right? Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @Fawn No, it is not.  You could run it and see that for yourself.

Comment: List<ExpandedHomeSlider> expandedSliderList = new List<ExpandedHomeSlider>();
            //var expandedSliderList = new List<string>();
            
            foreach (SPListItem item in myItems)
            {
                ExpandedHomeSlider ExplanatoryText = item["Explanatory Text"].ToString();
                expandedSliderList.Add(ExplanatoryText);       
            }  @Servy I don't know how to convert the object then add it to the list?

Comment: @Fawn Well, I showed you how to do that in this answer.  You could just copy/paste it, although I would *strongly* suggest that you take the time to learn how to create a new `ExpandedHomeSlider` object and set its value.  If you don't, I highly doubt you'll be able to do much else with your application and you would likely be better off going back and reading an intro book or taking some programming classes.

Comment: I wish I understood concepts better. I definitely need to learn more. Thanks.